# Numeric arrays with the same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function for `dropdown list`, which shows me the names for filtering `results` from two different `queries`. The one with the `numeric` `value` from `1-4` and the other with `10-110`, some of the results have the same `strings`:

```
function filter_workhires($status) {
    $status = array();
    $status[1] = 'booked';
    $status[70] = 'booked';
    $status[2] = 'partiallyattended';
    $status[90] = 'partiallyattended';
    $status[3] = 'fullyattended';
    $status[100] = 'fullyattended';
    $status[4] = 'notattended';
    $status[80] = 'notattended';
    $status[10] = 'status_user_cancelled';
    $status[20] = 'status_session_cancelled';
    $status[30] = 'status_declined';
    $status[40] = 'status_requested';
    $status[50] = 'status_approved';
    $status[60] = 'status_waitlisted';
    $status[110] = 'status_not_set';

    return $status;
}
```

In this form, I get `double names` for examle `booked`. How to `combine` the `statuses` according to the strings they show?

Comment: From the above array, please post a sample of your desired output.

Comment: do you want something like booked=1,70 or an array with unique values?

Answer (score 2):

```
return array_unique($status);
```

That's about it :)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => booked
    [2] => partiallyattended
    [3] => fullyattended
    [4] => notattended
    [10] => status_user_cancelled
    [20] => status_session_cancelled
    [30] => status_declined
    [40] => status_requested
    [50] => status_approved
    [60] => status_waitlisted
    [110] => status_not_set
)
```

Comment: It works halfway. It shows all statuses now with one string. But if I choose `fullyattended` from the dropdown, it shows only the statuses from the query with `3`, because it is above the query with `100`.

Comment: So how can one status string have two ids?

Comment: because, they are from different db querries.

Comment: So how do you want them? In a comma separated list? Select boxes cant have multiple values for one option

Comment: Now they show in the dropdown list and under `booked` etc. I have two `booked`, because `1` and `70` bring the same status. I need to be able to choose the single `booked` and to show me results for both statuses.

Comment: which is what my answer (below) does for you. When someone chooses 'partiallyattended' you get the $status['partiallyattended'] element and it returns the 2 ID's 2 & 90.

Answer (score 0):

Change it around so the description is the array key and the ID of the status is the value. When you build the array and you hit a duplicate you can then add multiple ID's to the value in some kind of structure like a comma separated string. So you end up with:

```
     $status['booked'] = '70';
     $status['partiallyattended'] = '2, 90';
     $status['fullyattended'] = '3, 10';
...
```

When someone chooses an item you explode the value and get all the ID's that relate to that status.